# why docker-compose up is failing on windows?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

below is my `docker-compose.yml` code

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

when I try `docker-compose up` it throw below error

```
[+] Running 0/1
 - Container recipe-app-api-app-1  Starting                                                                        0.7s
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "docker-compose": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

when I replace the command with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it work fine, or even I directly copy `docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` and execute it work fine.

I am using windows 11 terminal, and below is my Dockerfile, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
FROM python:3.12.1-alpine3.19
LABEL maintainer="jtelemarketing.com"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt .

COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    pip install --upgrade pop && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV == "true" ]; \
        then  pip install -r /requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi

ENV PATH="C:\Program Files\Python38\:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

The command inside the docker-compose file should not use `docker-compose`, but rather only `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` since you already are inside your docker container.

You cannot execute `docker` or `docker-compose` commands inside the container itself. (Well, except if docker runs inside the container, but I doubt that this is possible).

For reference: [documentation on docker-compose command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#command).
Setting this is essentially the same as setting `CMD` in the dockerfile, and this simply specifies commands that are executed "on startup" in the container.

Comment: Just for info - it is possible to run docker in docker (dind), though in general I wouldn't suggest it :)